# How can I set Icon on Gluon Mobile based project?

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

Since the `start()` method is final (cannot be overridden), and `primaryStage` has a private access in Mobile Application how can I set Icon on my program?

Comment: See for instance [Notes sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/notes/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/samples/notes/Notes.java#L50).

Comment: Sorry... I didn't pay enough attention to automatically plug-in generated project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a list of icons to a `Stage` instance:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().addAll(icon1, icon2, ...);
```

, where icon1, icon2 are instances of the `Image` class. The [Image Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) explains that BMP, PNG, GIF and JPEG are the required formats but if I remember well, you can add a picture with the ICO format: `icon1 = new Image("/.../logo.ico");`

You can add all your icons to your application using that method. As explained in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#getIcons--) :

> The images should be different sizes of the same image and the best size will be chosen, eg. 16x16, 32,32.